# If Boa Constrictors don’t have eyelids, how was the one at the zoo able to wink at Harry?

Tags: harry-potter

Apparently, there's a snake mentioned in *Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone* that's able to do this–

> *The snake suddenly opened its beady eyes. Slowly, very slowly, it raised
>   its head until its eyes were on a level with Harry's.*
>
> ***It winked.***
>
> *Harry stared. Then he looked quickly around to see if anyone was
>   watching. They weren't. He looked back at the snake and winked, too.*

---

*What the heck?* How is this possible? According to the [Anatomy of Boa Constrictors](http://www.ehow.com/about_6123564_anatomy-boa-constrictor.html) (emphasis mine):

> **Eyes and Ears**
>
> Boa constrictors have eyes with straight, vertical pupils that can take in a lot of light to help the animal hunt at night. **They do not have eyelids, but instead rely on an ocular scale that covers the eye to protect it from dirt**, dust and other debris. Like all snakes, boas do not have external ears, but use a weak set of internal ears to sense nearby vibrations.

Reinforced in the book *Boas and Pythons to the World*; they simply do not have eyelids!

> By the time we reach the pythons and boas we have seen an array of scale ... and granular in Boa Constrictors, large and distinctly imbricate (overlapping) in the ... **Although lacking eyelids**, snakes possess transparent eye coverings known as 'brilles' ...

And yes, this snake *is* a boa constrictor.

> The snake jabbed its tail at a little sign next to the glass. Harry
>   peered at it.
>
> Boa Constrictor, Brazil

[image]

#### So how did this boa constrictor defy biological logic and wink at Harry?

---

If it's simply a matter of Muggles not recognising a magical creature and placing it in a zoo, is it confirmed by J.K. Rowling? <sub>Or as Mithrandir points out, a case of JK Rowling bad *science*?</sub>

Comment: Magic? How does Harry fly on a broom stick?

Comment: Apparently it was not a boa constrictor - maybe those idiot muggles captured some magical animal that _looked_ like a boa constrictor.

Comment: Gallifreyan may have a point.  In the original Fantastic Beasts book (I still do not know how they made a movie our of a completely plotless book) there was a species of magical dog that looked exactly like bull terriers except for their forked tails.  Some wizards kept these magic dogs as pets and docked their tails to avoid muggle suspicion.  So there is a precedent for magical creatures being confused with mundane creatures by muggles.

Comment: Sounds like another case of JKR math - except JKR science ;)

Comment: Do we have any evidence that snakes in the HP universe don't have eyelids? That "Anatomy of Boa Constrictors" thing seems to be referring to snakes in the real world.

Comment: @Voronwë - This isn't a real-life boa constrictor, it's a HP boa constrictor. Remember that we're dealing with a universe where the Playstation came out before 1994.

Comment: @ibid Good point. Let's wait and see if anyone manages to dig up a relevant interview.

Comment: In the film, it's actually a Burmese Python (for some reason). Doesn't change anything, because it's not like _any_ snake is capable of winking, but I felt like I should mention it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the only thing JK ever said about the Zoo snake is that it's **not** Nagini, and that was only in response to a fake quote claiming she said it was.

Comment: I think there are bigger issues than that :P Apparently not only can it read, but it even knows what is written on the sign next to its tank. It apparently managed to speak a kind of Spanish parseltongue (adiosss amigo) which harry was able to interpret :P

Comment: It looks less like an actual wink and more like the snake is moving its "brow bone" down and its "cheek" up to force itself to "wink". The movement of its head reinforces the idea that it is taking a lot of effort for the snake to pull it off. I don't see any actual eyelid, which is required for making an official wink.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the story is set in our world, the only way a snake can change the visual perception of its eye is, when it is losing its skin. Some time before losing the skin, the eye gets "milky". The eye can appear more clear again when the skin is pressed against the eye again. Ignoring the movie and sticking to the book only, it is theoretically possible that the snake was in a state shortly before losing its skin. The eye was milky, but by moving within the skin that it was about lose, it could generate the impression of winking - which could have been done on purpose by the snake in the context of the story.

Comment: That's an interesting theory! Seems like this is going to be as good an answer as I can get. Enjoy the 25 rep.

Answer (score -1):

It also bears noting, that sometimes, depending on the lighting and surroundings a boas eye can appear almost entirely black, and then shift to the shades of colors with the vertical pupil. Mine does this all the time. Especially depending on what time of day it is. It fools my children all the time as to whether she is sleeping or not. They think it is an eyelid, and I have to remind them she does not have an eyelid as we think of it. Further, it is clearly a snake that is not real, but computer generated for that purpose. special effects work wonders.